# VSTO 2003-2010 add-in compatibility

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin

I want to create an Office add-in compatible with Office 2003, 2007 and 2010. VS2008 allows for add-in 2003/2007 creation while VS2010 allows 2007/2010. I have both installed.

I have developed 2007/2010 add-ins before as a 2007 add-in that worked automatically with Office 2010.

The problem I am facing now is the lack of ribbon interface in Office 2003 and how to structure the project so that a single add-in is compatible with Office 2003-2010.

Considering differences between various Office versions (especially 2003 to 2007/2010) is it at all possible to have a single add-in for all?

Comment: If you are interested please commit for this : stackoverflow.com/documentation/outlook-addin/commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using VSTO, you'll probably need different add-ins (see the [table of compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSTO) in the English Wikipedia article about VSTO).

If (1) you need to bring your solution rapidly to the market, and if (2) you have reasons to belief that your codebase will need frequent updates in the future, you may consider to use a third-party tool like Add-in Express, which lets you create what you need with less headaches.

Comment: Third party solution is not an option for me. It appears I need to build at least 2 add-ins, one for 2003 and the other for 2007/2010. Thanks!

Comment: Not really, you just need two sets of UI code. Your ribbon code can be in the form of XML or created via the designer, while the 2003 version would use commandbars model code. It is not difficult to either run the commandbars code and hook up the events OR load the XML file at startup based on the application.Version

Comment: having said that I agree with Domke that given the low cost of Addin Express it is a suitable solution for teams or individuals that don't have the capital to spend on supporting a more complex deployment and release process.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I'm developing a Shared Add-In for Office using Visual Studio 2010, and I had same requirement for Office versions. And it actually loads in those offices (event though Microsoft says VS 2010 plugin isn't compatible with Office 2003). I check version using Application.Version. If it's < 12 then I use CommandBars to programatically build menu. Otherwise, I use the ribbon extension (load from xml) to build menu.

**UPDATE** You'll have to keep in mind, that some features aren't available in Office 2003. For example TextRange2.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a single add-in, which targets 2003, 2007 & 2010 versions of Outlook.
I did this with VS2008, VSTOSE and PIA2003, along with Outlook 2003 on my dev machine.  I'm not how this will scale up to office/document-level add-ins, but it may work.

You will, however, need to detect the version of Outlook/Office on each client and install the appropriate PIA.

This can be done using [Component Checker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332051%28office.12%29.aspx).  In each Bootstrapper package you can then check to see, which version exists and only install that package when applicable.  For example in the product.xml for the bootstrapper package you would have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<InstallChecks>
    <ExternalCheck Property="Office2003Exists" PackageFile="ComponentCheck.exe" Arguments="{3EC1EAE0-A256-411D-B00B-016CA8376078}"/>
    <ExternalCheck Property="Office2003PIAExists" PackageFile="ComponentCheck.exe" Arguments="{14D3E42A-A318-4D77-9895-A7EE585EFC3B}"/>
</InstallChecks>


<Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="o2003pia.msi" Arguments="" EstimatedInstalledBytes="30000000" EstimatedInstallSeconds="60">
        <InstallConditions>
            <BypassIf Property="Office2003Exists" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="0" />
            <BypassIf Property="Office2003PIAExists" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="0" />
            <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
        </InstallConditions>

        <ExitCodes>
            <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
            <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
            <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
            <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
        </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
</Commands>
```

The product ids for 2007 are:

```
Outlook : 0638C49D-BB8B-4CD1-B191-050E8F325736 
PIA: ED569DB3-58C4-4463-971F-4AAABB6440BD
```

The product ids for 2010 are:

```
Outlook : CFF13DD8-6EF2-49EB-B265-E3BFC6501C1D
PIA: 1D844339-3DAE-413E-BC13-62D6A52816B2
```

This does mean you will have to include the pre-requisites into your installer package, rather than allowing for downloads, which will obviously increase download sizes.

You will also only be able to use methods etc that are in 2003.  Also, any toolbars you create will be basic, as you won't have full control of the Ribbon.  You can still add buttons etc as you would in 2003 & 2007.  They will appear in their own ribbon group in 2010.

One word of advice though, in my solution, I created a separate assembly for anything that didn't interact with Outlook.  That way, should requirements change in the future, I can easily split the add-ins to target specific versions, without affecting the main core functionality of the add-in.